# What happens when Computer shuts off unexpectedly?

Tags: power-supply, shutdown

I want to ask that what happens when laptop just shuts down unexpectedly due to power failure or like (of course other than shutting off properly)?

I mean what happens to hardware? What happens to OS and programs running? Do they get corrupted or something similar?

Comment: Nothing really happens to hardware other than it powers down unexpectedly, which does not harm it, A good OS will recover from this unexpected shutdown on reboot. Software can lose data when this happens, depends on what the program is, what it will lose or corrupt.

Comment: What Moab said. Everything. Simply. Just. Stops. It doesn't *do* anything. Except in the case of hard drives, where the drive will physically retract the heads and park them, SSDs with power-loss protection will complete in-flight writes.

Comment: @Moab when we say 'good os', does it include Ubuntu for our purpose?

Comment: Good is whatever you think is good, My opinion was one that can recover from an unexpected shutdown gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times the most common thing that happen is nothing about which to be too much worried.

**BTW**

- If the *HDD* were writing, at the new start of the disk, the heads of the drive will jump to the starting position. They can become more sensible than usual to damage due to vibration and displacement of the whole computer.

  > Frequent power outages can reduce a hard drive’s physical lifespan. The read-and-write head, which hovers over the spinning platters during operation, snaps back into its original position upon power loss. This sudden movement can cause tiny imperfections that accumulate over time, increasing the likelihood of a “head crash”: a malfunction that occurs when the head touches and scrapes the platter surfaces, effectively destroying the hard drive.
- The problem is not only related with the *power down* but even with the *power up*.

  > ... although power outages will not cause direct harm to computer hardware other than data drives, it’s possible for power outages to be accompanied **by power surges**, which can cause severe damage to hardware.
- On the other side you should have **data corruption** that the computer is writing, or using to send signals.

  > One of the first things that will happen, is that the memory DIMMs will no longer be refreshed properly (DRAM needs to be refreshed constantly otherwise it will lose its data) and very rapidly, the memory will contain only garbage. The hard drives and DMA controller however, will run a bit longer; so if data is being written to disk, the DMA controller will keep reading data from memory, but it has no idea that this data is corrupted.
- So you can **lose data** not synced with the *HDD*, you can have some mess with **partition table** especially if you were moving files or if the filesystem was delaying the writing operations, for sure you will empty the temporary  directory...

  > `sync` writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.  This can
  >   include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes,
  >   and delayed reads and writes.  This must be implemented by the kernel ...
  >     The **kernel keeps data in memory** to avoid doing (relatively slow) disk
  >   reads and writes.  This improves performance, but **if the computer
  >   crashes, data may be lost or the file system corrupted as a result.**
- You will lose all the program unsaved, the list of the undo actions in some smart program, the history of the shells... of course all the connections (sockets), the authentications, the links to the file created for you on internet...and I do not want to think if you have an [encrypted disk](https://superuser.com/a/121028/257269)...

**References**

- [Is TrueCrypt robust against data corruption?](https://superuser.com/q/38414/257269)
- [The Effects Power Outages Can Have On Your Computer](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/effects-power-outages-can-computer/)
- [Why power outages are bad for your data](http://www.halfgaar.net/why-power-failures-are-bad-for-your-data)
- [sync(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sync)

Comment: Also, operating systems that use write caching, such as Windows, may not have written items that you *thought* were saved to disk (and even that showed up in a file viewer).

Comment: Thanks @Hastur for that detailed answer and DrMoishe for additional comment.

Comment: Regarding power surges, don't you think built-in stabilizer in AC adapters of laptops are enough to protect against such power surges.